# Is there a way to render a TSX file when loading http://localhost:8080/test?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm really a newbie in front-end development. I'm currently involved in a project that does front-end development. I hope I can explain this clearly.

Whenever I call http://localhost:8080/test, it is loaded by `page1.jsp`.

Now I would like to load a TSX file instead of a JSP. I tried changing my `<welcome-file>` from `page1.jsp` to `html/js/page2.tsx` in `web.xml` but I don't know why it is not working.
What happened is that a download file window will pop up instead of loading http://localhost:8080/test.
I placed the TSX file in the `html/js` directory because that's where the package for Typescript and React is located. By the way, the TSX file I'm talking about is a React component that uses Typescript.

1. Is it possible to configure the web.xml to render the TSX file? If not, is there any other way for me to load it?
2. Is web.xml still important if I want to load a TSX file?

Comment: Browsers only read file types html, css, and js (JavaScript). Everything else needs to be "transpiled". Otherwise the browser just downloads it so the user can open it in a program that reads that file type :)

Answer (score 0):

No, for several reasons:

1. A .jsp is a "Java server page". You are probably running an application server like Tomcat (I haven't done that in fifteen years or so, so bear with me). It is compiled into a Servlet, which then runs to produce your page as output. Your .tsx file doesn't fit in that process.
2. Your application server probably has a directory somewhere where you can put *static files* that don't need to be run on the server side; see if you have a "WebContent" directory or so. In it you can place pure HTML files, Javascript files, fixed images and so on.
3. But if you put your TSX file there, your browser still won't be able to use it: browsers don't understand Typescript. Typescript needs to be *compiled* into Javascript, and if you put the resulting .js file there, then a HTML file could use it (with a  tag), and that would work.
4. But your file isn't only Typescript, it's a *tsx* -- it probably also contains JSX, which also needs to be translated to Javascript.
5. There are also dependencies, like React, that you'll also need to download in your HTML.
6. On the whole this is what a bundler like Webpack is for (if you used create-react-app, for instance, you'll get a working Webpack configuration from the start). It can create a "bundle.js" containing all the Javascript needed in one file, including all the dependencies and all your TSX code compiled to Javascript.

Place *that* in a WebContent or similar directory, call *that* from a  tag in some HTML file -- and you'll hopefully get a nice error message in the console that'll lead you to the first thing I forgot to mention :-)